# How to add a very small number and a very large number

Tags: java, precision, numerical-methods

I am pretty new to Java. I am learning numerical computation at the moment. How does one add and multiply a very small number and a very large number, say something of order $10^{-20}$ and something of order $10^{20}$ to arbitrary precision.

Comment: If double doesn't have enough precision for you big decimal might be what you need. You get a performance hit though

Comment: I tried double. However, it does not work out as it simply ignored the small number part.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.  From the Javadoc:

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.

and:

> The BigDecimal class gives its user complete control over rounding behavior.

For your example:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal("10e20");
        BigDecimal small = new BigDecimal("10e-20");
        BigDecimal ans = big.add(small);

        System.err.println("Answer: " + ans);
    }
}
```

Running gives the following:

```
$ java Main
Answer: 1000000000000000000000.00000000000000000010
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (didn't count the zeros). You may find other methods to construct 10^20/10^-20 more suitable.

```
System.out.println( new BigDecimal("0.0000000000000000000000000000001").add( new BigDecimal
        ("100000000000000000000000000000000")));
```